# What happen with blocks released?

Tags: oracle

I have the next doubt:

The blocks released from a segment are only reusable for the same segment?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DELETE`-ing data does not release blocks, the blocks will be marked as empty, but they will still belong to the same segment, so blocks will be reusable only for the same segment.

`TRUNCATE`, depending on the option used, may drop the segment, which releases all blocks. It may reduce the segment to its minimal size, which releases all blocks except that part. Or it may leave the segment as it is, which does not release any blocks at all.

An `ALTER TABLE ... MOVE` or `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` rebuilds the segment, releasing the original blocks.

An `ALTER TABLE ... SHRINK` may or may not release some of the blocks, depending on the option used (`SHRINK SPACE` vs `SHRINK SPACE COMPACT`).

And these are just the common operations.

So my simplified answer is: no. When blocks are released from a segment as above, that space can be reused by another segments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  And it's not just the individual block, it's the entire extent. Once an extent is allocated for a segment, the blocks that make up that extent always belong to that extent (at least until some real re-organization is performed) and that extent always belongs to the segment for which it was allocated.  Doesn't matter if the blocks contain data or not.

Comment: it does not matter if the segment is a table or an index?

Comment: You ask if it matters if the segment is a table or an index.  Read the sections "Overview of Extents" and "Overview of Segments" in the Concepts manual and see if the make any distinction between index and table segments.